# How to find what **options parameters are?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

I am using tkinter. When I want to learn more about the methods I go into their library.

> i.e. from tkinter import filedialog

One of the methods I am looking at is this:

```
def askdirectory (**options):
    "Ask for a directory, and return the file name"
    return Directory(**options).show()
```

I know the the `**options` parameter means it accepts an arbitrary number of arguments and/or keyword arguments.

I don't understand how to find the parameters for `options` for that method. I tried looking in deeper into the method classes but I get lost to where to look.

I want to be able to find what the parameters can be by reading the library code so I can apply that to reading and understanding other python libraries quicker.

Comment: You mean what keys are acceptable? Look at the `Directory()` class and see what that accepts. There will be a `Directory.__init__` and / or `Directory.__new__` method defined, directly in the `Directory` class or a parent class. Where does `Directory` *come* from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't going to have a lot of luck getting the options from the code itself. Tkinter is a wrapper around a tcl/tk interpreter, and a lot of the options are simply passed through tkinter to the underlying tcl interpreter.

The definitive source of documentation for the available options can be found in the tcl/tk man pages: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm